# Is the phrase 'on on demand' correct?

Tags: phrases, doubled-words

Here I am referring to TV broadcasting channels such as Sky TV who have a service called 'On Demand', now I have heard numerous people including family members say something like this:

> 'We can watch this on on demand'

Note the double use of the word `on` here, I find this quite unusual as saying it twice just seems a bit weird, does the second `on` substitute the first one? Or is this just fine?

Comment: We can watch this on "On Demand".

Comment: That doesn't answer my question does it?

Comment: @user3574492 Yes, it does. In Josh's example, "On Demand" is a proper noun, indivisible, with a fixed meaning independent of its component words.  Just like "HBO" is. Just as "I can watch this on HBO" is not a problem grammatically or syntactically, neither is "I can watch this on On Demand".

Comment: "On-Demand" is the name of the service and therefore a proper noun. While double "on" is probably *not* needed to convey meaning, it is technically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Sky TV service is named "On Demand" and your family members refer to this service:

> *'We can watch this on On Demand'*

This would be correct as it is a personal name.

But if your family members refer to the general availability on the internet they should use:

> *'We can watch this on demand'*